# Error: type 'RequestCallBack' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a simple app so that when the user presses the call-back button the callBack form pops-up, as I am implementing it using named routes so while pressing the call-back button I am getting this error: type 'RequestCallBack' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' while routing to callback form screen.

This is my routing file:

routes.dart

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  // Getting arguments passed in while calling Navigator.pushNamed
  final argsFireBaseUser = settings.arguments;
  final argsString = settings.arguments;

  switch (settings.name) {
     case '/request-call-back':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => RequestCallBack(user: argsFireBaseUser, 
                                mobileNumber: argsString)
         );
     default:
        return _errorRoute();
  }
}
```

screen.dart

```
final String mobileNumber;
Screen({
  Key key,
  @required this.mobileNumber,
})  : assert(mobileNumber != null),
    super(key: key);

onPressed:() {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/request-call-back', 
             arguments: RequestCallBack(user: user,mobileNumber: 
                          widget.mobileNumber,));
}
```

requestcallback.dart

```
class RequestCallBack extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mobileNumber;
  final FirebaseUser user;
  RequestCallBack({
    Key key,
    @required this.user,
    @required this.mobileNumber,
  })  : assert(mobileNumber != null && user != null),
        super(key: key);

@override
_RequestCallBackState createState() => _RequestCallBackState();
```

}

Comment: Where is the error happening? What line of code specifically?

Comment: Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/request-call-back', 
             arguments: RequestCallBack(user: user,mobileNumber: 
                          widget.mobileNumber,));

Comment: Any particular reason you are passing the widget as an argument to the route? Because that is the problem right there.

Comment: widget.mobilenumber is a String type and it is passed to request callback page in mobile number String. And user is a firebase user so it is passed as a user to request call back screen. @Abion47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to pass whole widget over there. You have to pass those arguments as a list as following.

```
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/request-call-back', 
             arguments: [user, 
                          widget.mobileNumber]);
```

In navigation route you also have to just pass list as following.

```
 case '/request-call-back':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => RequestCallBack(data:settings.arguments) // changed
         );
```

Now in stfull widget you can accept data as following.

```
class RequestCallBack extends StatefulWidget {
  final List data;
  RequestCallBack({
    Key key,
    @required this.data,
  })  : assert(data != null),
        super(key: key);
```

Now in State widget you can separate data.

```
final String mobileNumber = widget.data[0];
final FirebaseUser user = widget.data[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a RequestCallback as arguments of the pushNamed:

```
arguments: RequestCallBack(user: user,mobileNumber: widget.mobileNumber,));
```

But you are retrieving arguments as FirebaseUser:

```
final argsFireBaseUser = (RequestCallBack) settings.arguments;
```

You should first retrive arguments as a object:

```
final rc = settings.arguments;
```

And then get the user:

```
argsFireBaseUser = rc.user;
```